# How to generate the nth numbers containing only 2 types of digits?

Tags: algorithm, c++11

We define a **special number** as a number containing only 4s and 7s.

Let's see examples: `447` , `477` , `444` and `777` are **special numbers** while `407` isn't.

I need help to understand what is the **law/rule** to generate the `Nth`  special number.

I tried the code below but it didn't work

```
int x[2000];
int k=0;

void dfs( int a ) {
  if(k==1021)
    return;
  x[k++]=a;
  dfs(a*10+4);
  dfs(a*10+7);
}

dfs(4);
dfs(7);
```

Any solution or idea about how to do it  ?

Comment: are you sure you're using C++? Looks like C to me!

Comment: they are very similar in syntax . have you tried c++ before ?

Comment: Yes, I'm an avid C++ programmer, that's why I ask; this is valid, pedantically valid, C.

Comment: Your code isn't idiomatic C++, hence the legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this we can use binary. Call the 4s as 0s and the 7s as 1s, since 7>4. Say we are looking for the nth special number. Define k as the number of special numbers with fewer digits that the nth special number. Now, we see how binary can be used. Say we know that the 10th special number has 3 digits, and that  k=6. We are looking for the 10-6=4th number into the list of 3-digit special numbers.

`4` - `0`      `77` - `11`

`7` - `1`      `444` - `000`

`44` - `00`      `447` - `001`

`47` - `01`      `474` - `010`

`74` - `10`      `477` - `011` <-Here

Mapping them to binary like shown, the problem becomes easier. The number of m-digit special numbers is going to be 2^m, and remember that the sum of the first m powers of two is 2^(m+1)-1. If we have a 3-digit number, then we find k by summing the 1 digit and 2 digit numbers, leaving us with 2^0+2^1+2^2=2^3-1. Excluding 0-digit numbers we have 2^3-2 as k, and this generalizes to 2^digits-2. In order to find the number of digits, we need to find out how many powers of two are below n. This is simply log2(n), but we have to line it up and get an integer so we take floor(log2(n+1)). From here, we simply use the binary representation of n-k-1 and then use bitwise functions to extract each digit and add the digit to our answer.

```
int nthspecialnum( int n )
{
    int digits = (int)(log2(n+1));
    int k = pow( 2, digits ) - 2;
    int binary = n - k - 1;
    int answer = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < digits; i++ ) {
        bool is7 = ((binary >> i) % 2) == 1;
        answer += (is7 ? 7 : 4)*pow( 10, i );
    }
    return answer;
}
```

These numbers get large decently quickly, so if you're looking for large `n` and don't want negative numbers to come out, you can simply save the digits in an array rather than an integer and print them out sequentially.

Comment: By the way I can check with a better code but what I need is **not** to check but I need **the idea of generating special numbers**

Comment: @Meyer Oh I think I understand, you want a function to generate the nth special number (By actual generating, not by counting until the nth)?

Comment: @Meyer I updated my answer, this should be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your code is broken**

Your code doesn't work because your termination condition depends on a global variable `k` which is not reset before the second call `dfs(7)`. So this call terminates without producing *any* new special number. So in the end you miss all special numbers starting with a `7`.

You could fix that by just calling: `dfs(0)` and discarding the first entry of you `x` array. But the whole program is badly written. Relying on global variable inside a function is a call for a disaster.

**Algorithm to generate all special numbers**

If the number is between 0 and 100 then it has got either 0, 1 or 2 digits.

So basically all special numbers are: 4, 7, 44, 47, 74, 77.

If you want to extend to a number `d` of digits, then you can use a binary number of `d` bits. Choose that a bit whose value is `0` will be a decimal digit `4`, and a bit whose value is `1` will translate into a decimal digit `7`. Then by enumerating all the values between `0` and `2^d-1` you can generate all the special numbers.

In the previous case we enumerated all special numbers with:

- 1 bit, which translates into 2 special numbers: `4` ad `7`
- 2 bits, which translates into 4 special numbers: `44`, `47`, `74`, `77`

**How to get the Nth special number**
First of all we consider a 1 based indexing.

You just need to remark that the count of special numbers whose binary representation has got less that `d` bits is: `2^1+2^2+...+ 2^d = 2(2^d-1) = 2^(d+1)-2`

You can do a simple loop incrementing `d` until `2^(d+1)-2` is not strictly inferior to `n`. This tells you should use a `d` bits binary representation for `n`. You substract `2^d-2` to `n` and you substract `1` because we use a `1` based indexing. The final number can now pass through the steps described above to generate a special number.

Example: 5th special numbers

```
2^2-2 = 2 <  5   => d+1 > 2
2^3-2 = 6 >= 5   => d+1 = 3  => d = 2

n-2^d+2-1 = 5-4+2-1 = 2 = 10b (using 2 bits as d = 2)

=> 5th special number is: 74
```

Comment: thanks but I know it . what i need is the law to generate the from **0** to **10^100** for example

Comment: @Meyer See my update. For 10^100, you will need to output more than 2^100 special numbers and I doubt it is feasible.

Comment: @Meyer, seriously, don't ask new questions in the comments.

Comment: @Meyer you said *"thanks but I know it ."*, but you don't seem to get fjardon's idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

i try to follow your idea to answer this question.
Maybe somebody will get help from this.

```
int x[2000];
int k = 0;
const int num_len = 8;

void dfs(int a, int level)
{
    if (level > num_len)
        return;
    x[k++] = a;
    dfs(a * 10 + 4, level + 1);
    dfs(a * 10 + 7, level + 1);
}

int main()
{
    memset(x, 0, sizeof(x));
    dfs(0, 0);
    sort(x, x+k);

    int nth;
    cin >> nth;
    cout << x[nth] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer: Test for 7 and 4:

```
bool check (unsigned int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        return false;
    while(number != 0) {
        unsigned int digit = number % 10;
        if( digit != 4 && digit != 7 )
            return false;
        number /= 10; // integer division, ie. "rounding down"
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int number = 0; number <= 100; number ++) {
        if(check(number)) 
             do_what_ever_you_want(number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you even understand my question title  ?

Comment: maybe not; but honestly, I'm pretty good at English, so I'm afraid you should rephrase it if I didn't understand it.